# Calculating $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Solving without L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)$$

That's

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}\right)-\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)$$

I have been taught to get the highest exponents, so...

$$\sqrt{4x^2}-\sqrt{4x^2}$$

It's the same for both sides, no?

$$2x-2x$$

$$-\infty+\infty$$

Which is wrong. The correct answer is

$$\frac{1}{4}$$

Why? I always just grab the highest exponent ($\sqrt{4x^2}$) and work with it. But this time it didn't go well.

Comment: Already your first step is wrong. The rule $\lim(f+g)=\lim f + \lim g$ is only valid if the two limits on the right-hand side are *finite*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2-x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2-x}\right)\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2-x}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2-x}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{4x^2-6-4x^2+x}{\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2-x}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x-6}{x\left(\sqrt{4-\frac{6}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{x}}\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-\frac{6}{x}}{\sqrt{4-\frac{6}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4-\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$=\frac{1-0}{\sqrt{4-0}+\sqrt{4-0}}=\frac{1}{2+2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: $\dfrac{1}{2+2} = \dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: After rationalizing, shouldn't it have been $4x^2-6-4x^2\color{red}{-x}$ instead of $4x^2-6-4x^2\color{red}{+x}$?

Comment: Notice, $(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2\color{red}{-x}})(\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2\color{red}{-x}})=4x^2-6-(4x^2\color{red}{-x})$$$=4x^2-6-4x^2\color{red}{+x}$$

Comment: But isn't it $\sqrt{4x^2+x}$ instead of $\sqrt{4x^2-x}$?

Comment: No, because we substitute $x=-x$ then $x\to +\infty$

Comment: So basically a limit where $x\to-\infty$ is the same as $x\to+\infty$ as long as I invert all the $x$ signs? Of course $x^2$ would remain the same, but if I had $x^3$ it would become $-x^3$?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Hello, today I worked on this limit and forgot to do the "inverting" thing. My result was $-\frac{1}{4}$ instead of $\frac{1}{4}$. I can see that I should have inverted that, but it is unclear to me **why** should I invert it. Whenever I see a $x\to-\infty$ do I **have to** change it to $x\to\infty$? Because without inverting it the operation went smoothly as far as I am aware of.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: Use the identity: $\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B} = \dfrac{A-B}{\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}}$, and $\sqrt{4x^2\pm6} = x\sqrt{4\pm\dfrac{6}{x^2}}$

Comment: Does the first identity have a name I can search for?

Comment: Its a variant of the well known $A^2-B^2 = (A-B)(A+B)$.

Comment: I used the two things you showed me and progressed to $$\frac{-6-x}{\sqrt{4-\frac{6}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}}$$. While it does seem a bit better it is still not quite clear to me what to do with that.

Comment: You missed the $x$ in front of each square root, and divide the top by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2+x}}{\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2+x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{4x^2-6})^2-(\sqrt{4x^2+x})^2}{\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2+x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{4x^2-6-(4x^2+x)}{\sqrt{4x^2-6}+\sqrt{4x^2+x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(-x-6)/|x|}{\sqrt{4-6/x^2}+\sqrt{4+x/x^2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1+\frac{6}{x}}{\sqrt{4-\frac{6}{x^2}}+\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{x}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{4}}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: When you divide $(-x-6)/|x|$, why did you pick $|x|$ instead of $x$? Why is this allowed? Also, how can $(-x-6)/|x|$ become $1+\frac{6}{x}$? Dividing by infinity should be $0$, I think.

Comment: @ZolTunKul: In order to make manipulations inside the surds.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how can $(-x-6) / |x|$ result in $(1 + 6/x)$. Since $|x| = +\infty$, which is positive, how come the signs are shifted? I mean, $-x$ becomes $1$ (negative to positive) and $-6$ becomes $6/x$ (negative to positive). Shouldn't $(-x-6)$ be divided by just $x$? Since $x = -\infty$ then the signs can indeed by shifted. I think.

Comment: @ZolTunKul: Notice $x\to -\infty$ is not the same that $x=-\infty$ as it seems you are supposing. Instead, as $x\to -\infty$ we have that we can make $|x|$ as large as we want and $x<0$. So, $|x|=-x$, since $x<0$, then
$$\frac{-x-6}{|x|}=\frac{-x-6}{-x}=\frac{x+6}{x}=1+\frac{6}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $-1/x=y\implies y\to0^+, |y|=+y$

and $4x^2-6=\dfrac{4-6y^2}{y^2},\sqrt{4x^2-6}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-6y^2}}{|y|}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4-6y^2}}y$

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\sqrt{4x^2-6}-\sqrt{4x^2+x}\right)=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{4-6y^2}-\sqrt{4-y}}y$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{(4-6y^2)-(4-y)}{y(\sqrt{4-6y^2}+\sqrt{4-y})}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{y(1-6y)}{y(\sqrt{4-6y^2}+\sqrt{4-y})}$$

Cancel out $y$ as $y\ne0$ as $y\to0$

Then set $y=0$